# HTTP Status 404 in spring MVC

Tags: spring

```
    <servlet><servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping> 

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/**")
public class LoginController {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;


    @RequestMapping(value = {"/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginWelcome(ModelMap model) {
        System.out.println("yes come till here");


        return "login";
    }


}
```

This is my web.xml and controller class. Here when i running project getting 404 error. please help me. Control is no going to the controller even a single time.

Comment: Please goto the link to view the folder structure image http://i.stack.imgur.com/QLKFe.png

Comment: Here i am using tile so returning login tile. but before this controller should find and print the text written in the SOP

Answer (score 0):

I think, the reason of error is wrong request mapping.

For @RequestMapping with URI -

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/method"},method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String method(){
 return "method";
}
```

You can use "POSTER" or "POSTMAN" for checking.

Comment: its first page request that will come from the web.xml. i am not sending the request from the form action. method name is required in that case.

Comment: its a front controller request.ok